The code prints 1 line with 5 stars and others empty
This code worked in for loop perfectly but when I tried the same thing in while loop it is not working as expected. When I input n as 5 it should print basic inverted star pattern but instead it prints 1 line with 5 stars and other lines empty. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am new with programming and its my day 6 so please try to be a little gentle.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your input : ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
int i = 1;
int s = 1;
while(i<=n) {
    while(s<=n-i+1) {
        System.out.print("*");
        s++;
    } System.out.println(); 
    i++; 
}


You need to reset s to 0 after the inner while loop. Try to run through your code with a debugger to see for yourself.

You have to set s to 1 before the second loop:
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your input : ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
int i = 1;
while(i<=n) {
    int s = 1;  // Reset value of s here
    while(s<=n-i+1) {
        System.out.print("*");
        s++;
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
    i++; 
}


